# Read the last inserted row

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo

I have the following insert statement

```
global $dbUser;
global $dbPW;
$query = "INSERT INTO comments (post_id, text) VALUES (:post_id,:text)";
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $dbUser, $dbPW);
$statement = $db -> prepare($query);
$statement -> execute(array(':post_id' => $postId, ':text' => $text));
```

I want to read and return the inserted row **in the same transaction**.

I know I can get the

> $db->lastInsertId('id')

but and I know how to do a transaction in PDO but I can't find out how to do it with a prepared statement as above (which is the preferred method for security purposes IIRC).

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't connect in the function. Connect once per application and then use once connection throughout the code.

Comment: @YourCommonSense ok thanks, that means "$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $dbUser, $dbPW);" would be initialized once (say in my global include file) and re-used as a global variable?

Comment: yes, exactly. just make it `global $db;` in the function. Otherwise you'll spam DB server with multiple connects from single script execution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need no transactions here.
Just run $db->lastInsertId() if you need autogenerated id - that's all.

Comment: in that case it's true, in other cases I have formulas in the select-statement I don't want to have in other parts of the code again. Thanks for your valuable input!!